# Update panel on Telerik control

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

In my asp.net application there are several dropdown and textbox control which creates dynamically. So on select of dropdown while data is being fetched I want to show update progress on div. Also I dont want to post back call so whole page should not be refreshed.
Here is my code

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="filter-section">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                            <asp:Panel ID="ControlsParent" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:Panel>       
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="BtnShowReport" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" Text="Show Report" OnClick="BtnShowReport_Click" />
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am new to Telerik so dont have idea to use.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code insiode the Update Panel, I am using Simple asp and haven't used Telerik in following:

// you code codes here

```
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
 <asp:UpdateProgress DynamicLayout="true" ID="upProgSearch" DisplayAfter="1500" runat="server"   >
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="progressBackgroundFilter"></div>
        <div id="processMessage" style="width:100px;">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/images/Loading.gif" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

for preventng auto postback use `<triggers>` tags in update panel and use `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>` and specify the event name that causes postback and you don't want .